# Fetch all dates which is exists between start date and end date in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What will be the conditions of the dates which will fetch all dates
   which is lies between Start date and End Date.I'm using this query
   but it is not full fill these conditions.

```
@festivals = @festivals.where(:event_group_start=>params[:event_group_start]..(params[:event_group_end])) if (params[:event_group_start] && params[:event_group_end]).present?
```

Comment: What output does your `query` currently gives?

Comment: It's satisfying Start Date condition but not for End Date,Suppose our Start Date is 03-06-2014 and End Date is 21-06-2014.Actually the output will be with in these dates 03-06-2014 to 21-06-2014 , But Actual result is giving 03-06-2014 to 28-07-2014.

Comment: Can you inspect `@festivals` and post the output it gives please?

Comment: SELECT epoker_event_groups.*,epoker_countries.name,epoker_countries.iso FROM `epoker_event_groups` INNER JOIN `epoker_countries` ON `epoker_countries`.`ioc` = `epoker_event_groups`.`event_country` WHERE (`epoker_event_groups`.`event_group_start` BETWEEN '2014-06-03' AND '2014-06-28') ORDER BY epoker_event_groups.created_at DESC

Comment: This is the query what I'm getting.

Comment: This is the Output:--

Comment: !ruby/object:EventGroup
  attributes:
    id: 25
   event_group_start: 2014-06-21 00:00:00.000000000 Z
    event_group_end: 2014-06-28 00:00:00.000000000 Z
 - !ruby/object:EventGroup
  attributes:
    id: 24
    event_group_start: 2014-06-26 00:00:00.000000000 Z
    event_group_end: 2014-06-30 00:00:00.000000000 Z
   
- !ruby/object:EventGroup
  attributes:
    id: 23
    event_group_start: 2014-06-11 00:00:00.000000000 Z
    event_group_end: 2014-06-28 00:00:00.000000000 Z

Comment: Try giving like this `@festivals = @festivals.where('event_group_start >= ? and event_group_end <= ?',params[:event_group_start],params[:event_group_end]) if (params[:event_group_start] && params[:event_group_end]).present?`

Answer (score 0):

```
@festivals = @festivals.where(:event_group_start=>params[:event_group_start]..(params    [:event_group_end])) if (params[:event_group_start] && params[:event_group_end]).present?
```

your query select all festivals where event_group_start is equal to params[:event_group_start] and etc. If you want to search something that lies between then use this sintax

```
 @festivals = @festivals.where('event_group_start > ?', params[:event_group_start])
 @festivals = @festivals.where('event_group_end < ?', params[:event_group_end])
```

this will also check your params safety and prevent any sql injections. Do not use it's like

```
.where("event_group_end < #{params[:event_group_end]}")
```

it's not safe.